# How to remove combobox component when button is clicked flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox, flash-cs5

I'm having trouble with my combobox in flash cs5. 
I have created a combobox by following the guide here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa9.html

My AS3 code is as follows:

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox; 
import fl.data.DataProvider; 
import flash.net.navigateToURL; 

var sfUniversities:Array = new Array( 
    {label:"University of California, Berkeley",  
                data:"http://www.berkeley.edu/"}, 
    {label:"University of San Francisco",  
                data:"http://www.usfca.edu/"}, 
    {label:"San Francisco State University",  
                data:"http://www.sfsu.edu/"}, 
    {label:"California State University, East Bay",  
                data:"http://www.csuhayward.edu/"}, 
    {label:"Stanford University", data:"http://www.stanford.edu/"}, 
    {label:"University of Santa Clara", data:"http://www.scu.edu/"}, 
    {label:"San Jose State University", data:"http://www.sjsu.edu/"} 
); 

var aCb:ComboBox = new ComboBox(); 
aCb.dropdownWidth = 210; 
aCb.width = 200;  
aCb.move(150, 50); 
aCb.prompt = "San Francisco Area Universities"; 
aCb.dataProvider = new DataProvider(sfUniversities); 
aCb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler); 

addChild(aCb); 

function changeHandler(event:Event):void { 
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(); 
    request.url = ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data; 
    navigateToURL(request); 
    aCb.selectedIndex = -1; 
}
```

I also have a simple back button on the same frame as the combobox which when clicked takes you to a previous frame.

My button:

```
btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickBack);

function clickBack(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(333);
}
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the combobox stays on the screen. I want the combobox to be only visible in a single frame.

How do I get rid of the combobox once the button is clicked?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case use:

```
removeChild(aCb);
```

Remember to remove event listener if you want garbage collector to clean it (or use weak eventListener).